# C++ Open file dialog in window

Tags: c++, winapi

I have C++ code to show dialog chooser file. I want to the user can only chooser type file specified. My dialog can show type file specified but the user can input other type file in File name like my picture

[image]

So, how can I make the user only input File name and search type file specified in `lpstrFilter`? OR Can i disable File name box?

**This is my code**:

```
const wchar_t* ChooserFile(const char* typeFile)
{
    try
    {
        ZeroMemory( &sfn , sizeof( sfn));
        sfn.lStructSize = sizeof ( sfn );
        sfn.hwndOwner = NULL ;
        wchar_t w_syFile[MAX_PATH];
        //mbstowcs(w_syFile, syFile, strlen(syFile)+1);//Plus null
        size_t convertedChars = 0;
        mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, w_syFile, MAX_PATH, syFile, _TRUNCATE);
        sfn.lpstrFile = w_syFile ;
        sfn.lpstrFile[0] = _T('\0');
        sfn.nMaxFile = sizeof( syFile );

        //TypeFile
        sfn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("Microsoft Office Word Documents (*.xlsx)\0*.XLSX\0");

        sfn.nFilterIndex =1;
        sfn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL ;
        sfn.nMaxFileTitle = 0 ;
        sfn.lpstrInitialDir=NULL;

        //sfn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT|OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_ENABLEHOOK ;
        sfn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST|OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST|OFN_NOVALIDATE|OFN_HIDEREADONLY  ;
        if (GetOpenFileName( &sfn ) != TRUE)
        {
            wstrPathFile = TEXT("");
            return wstrPathFile.c_str();
        }

        DWORD  retval=0;
        //BOOL   success; 
        TCHAR  buffer[BUFSIZE]=TEXT(""); 
        TCHAR  buf[BUFSIZE]=TEXT(""); 
        TCHAR** lppPart={NULL};

        wchar_t wstrPath[BUFSIZE];
        retval = GetFullPathNameW(sfn.lpstrFile,sfn.nMaxFile,wstrPath,lppPart);
        if (retval==0)
        {
            wstrPathFile = TEXT("");
            return wstrPathFile.c_str();
        }
        std::wstring s(wstrPath);
        wstrPathFile = s;
        wcout<<wstrPathFile<<endl;
        return wstrPathFile.c_str();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        PrintToFile("ChooserFile","Error");
        wstrPathFile = TEXT("");
        return wstrPathFile.c_str();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the [FILEOKSTRING callback message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646870(v=vs.85).aspx) to reject file names you don't like.

Comment: if you're targeting Vista or later you you should be using the Common Item Dialog.  Then you can use the `IFileDialogEvents::OnFileOk` callback method. Return `S_OK` if you like the filename, or `S_FALSE` to reject.

Comment: Thanks @nwp, but i don't know how to using FILEOKSTRING. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Thanks theB, but i want to use this in win XP! Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

> I want to the user can only chooser type file specified.

You can't stop the user choosing whatever file they like by typing into the file name edit control. So, you should simply let them do that and instead validate that the file name matches your requirements.

You have a couple of options to do that:

1. Let the dialog return and if the file name does not meet your requirements, present the user with an error dialog letting them know what went wrong.
2. Supply a hook procedure in the `lpfnHook` member of the `OPENFILENAME` struct. That will get sent a [`CDN_FILEOK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646857.aspx) notification message when the user attempts to accept a file. Perform your validation in response to that message. If the file name does not meet requirements, show a message to that effect and return a non-zero value to force the dialog to remain open.

Comment: One more option to give the user less incentive to pick an illegal filename: Adjust the file name edit control's autocompletion (see [Using Autocomplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776884.aspx)).

Comment: Supply a hook procedure in the lpfnHook member of the OPENFILENAME struct. That will get sent a CDN_FILEOK notification message when the user attempts to accept a file. Perform your validation in response to that message. If the file name does not meet requirements, show a message to that effect and return a non-zero value to force the dialog to remain open.
=> Thanks David, Can you give me an example for this?

Comment: I'm sure you can do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is commenting out the `OFN_EXPLORER` and `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` flags, so you must already know about the existence of [Explorer-style hooking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960.aspx#_win32_Explorer_Style_Hook_Procedures).  As others have told you, you can use that hook to catch the [`CDN_FILEOK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646857.aspx) notification to accept/reject a selected filename.  For example:

```
UINT_PTR CALLBACK MyOFNHookProc(HWND hdlg, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uiMsg == WM_NOTIFY)
    {
        LPOFNOTIFY ofn = (LPOFNOTIFY) lParam;    
        if (ofn->hdr.code == CDN_FILEOK)
        {
            LPOPENFILENAMEW lpOFN = (LPOPENFILENAMEW) ofn->lpOFN;

            LPWSTR lpExt = PathFindExtensionW(lpOFN->lpstrFile);
            if (lstrcmpiW(lpExt, L".XLSX") != 0)
            {
                SetWindowLongPtr(hdlg, DWL_MSGRESULT, 1);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

std::wstring ChooserFile(const char* typeFile)
{
    OPENFILEAMEW sfn = {0};
    wchar_t w_syFile[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};
    size_t convertedChars = 0;

    sfn.lStructSize = sizeof(sfn);
    sfn.hwndOwner = NULL;
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, w_syFile, MAX_PATH, syFile, _TRUNCATE);
    sfn.lpstrFile = w_syFile;
    sfn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;

    //TypeFile
    sfn.lpstrFilter = L"Microsoft Office Word Documents (*.xlsx)\0*.XLSX\0";

    sfn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    sfn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    sfn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    sfn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;

    sfn.lpfnHook = &MyOFNHookProc;

    sfn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_NOVALIDATE | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_ENABLEHOOK;

    if (!GetOpenFileNameW(&sfn))
        return L"";

    WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};

    DWORD retval = GetFullPathNameW(sfn.lpstrFile, MAX_PATH, szPath, NULL);
    if ((retval == 0) || (retval > MAX_PATH))
        return L"";

    std::wstring wstrPath(szPath, retval);
    std::wcout << wstrPath << endl;
    return wstrPath;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Remy, It's worked. Can you tell me how to i set this dialog alway topmost? I have searched but i didn't found any think!

Comment: You have access to the dialog's HWND inside of the hook (`GetParent(hdlg)`), so you could call `SetWindowPos()` to set it to `HWND_TOPMOST`. But why do this? It is not standard UI practice to make a file dialog be on top of all running windows. If you just want to make sure the dialog cannot fall behind the zorder of a particular window, you should be setting the `sfn.hwndOwner` field instead.

Comment: Don't make it topmost. Set the owner of the dialog.